# Composer install --optimize-autoloader on production throws Service Provider not found

Tags: laravel-5, deployment, composer-php

I am developing an app using Laravel 5.5

What I've done in development environment with no error:

1. Run `composer require spatie/laravel-permission`
2. Added this Service Provider in `config/app.php`: `'providers' => [Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,];`

If I had the Service Provider registered before to install spatie/laravel-permission, then I guess I'd get the error "Service Provider" not found. That's what happened on production, because the app had the Service Provider already registered after I deployed it to production, so the deploy failed when running `composer install --optimize-autoloader` throwing the following error message:

```
[Symfony\\\\Component\\\\Debug\\\\Exception\\\\FatalThrowableError]        
Class 'Spatie\\\\Permission\\\\PermissionServiceProvider' not found
```

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have already added the autoload ServiceProvider in composer. You actually don't need to add it to your `config/app.php` file

See:  https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: OK, thanks. One more thing, what if I was using Laravel older than 5.4, which requires you to add the Service Provider to the `config/app.php` file? How to solve the `Service Provider not found` issue when deploying the application?